# How to stop the cookie invalidation after each time a blazor piece of code is changed and recompiled?

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly

I'm using a hosted Blazor WebAssembly project template and after setting up cookies as the main authentication method(also for APIs), everything is nice and dandy until I change a line of code(front-end or back-end), the automatic compilation kicks in and the webpage is reloaded(thanks to "Start without Debugging"), but this time the auth cookie seems invalidated and I no longer seem to be logged in.

Is there a way to stop this behaviour? Or a way to stop the cookie auth from changing between different compilations?

Following is my CookieAuthenticationEvents implementations/overrides:

```
public class CookieAuth : CookieAuthenticationEvents
{
    readonly IUserService UserRepository;

    public CookieAuth(IUserService userRepository)
    {
        UserRepository = userRepository;
    }

    public override Task RedirectToLogin(RedirectContext<CookieAuthenticationOptions> context)
    {
        context.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status401Unauthorized;
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
    public override Task RedirectToAccessDenied(RedirectContext<CookieAuthenticationOptions> context)
    {
        context.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status401Unauthorized;
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
    public override async Task ValidatePrincipal(CookieValidatePrincipalContext context)
    {
        var userPrincipal = context.Principal;

        var userId = (from c in userPrincipal.Claims
                                    where c.Type == ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier
                                    select c.Value).FirstOrDefault();

        var isTeacherAndBlocked = await UserRepository.IsTeacherAndIsBlocked(userId);

        if (isTeacherAndBlocked)
        {
            context.RejectPrincipal();
            await context.HttpContext.SignOutAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
            return;
        }

        var lastChanged = (from c in userPrincipal.Claims
                                             where c.Type == "LastChanged"
                                             select c.Value).FirstOrDefault();

        if (!DateTime.TryParse(lastChanged, out DateTime lastChangedDate))
        {
            context.RejectPrincipal();
            await context.HttpContext.SignOutAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
            return;
        }

        if (!await UserRepository.ValidateLastChanged(lastChanged, userId))
        {
            context.RejectPrincipal();
            await context.HttpContext.SignOutAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
        }
    }
}
```

Meanwhile `UserRepository.ValidateLastChanged(...)` checks whether the obtained date string matches the one in DB(it's a way to figure out if the user changed the password and then went to an old session from another device, in this case I want that kind of session invalidated)

Then there's the usual `Startup.cs` cookie configuration:

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
            .AddCookie(options =>
            {
                options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromHours(1);
                options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.Lax;
                options.Cookie.Name = "wtf";
                options.EventsType = typeof(CookieAuth);
                options.SlidingExpiration = true;
            });
```

Comment: Auth cookies can persist after rebuild (mine always do) so something must be configured to have them expire somehow, but without your code I can't say what that might be.

Comment: @TonyPacheco I added the cookie auth events handler and the startup setup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind, figured out that it was a comparison issue between dates as strings, just don't do it, go with ticks. :D

Comment: So do you get the bounty? XD

Comment: It doesn't seem :)